# nginx reverse proxy pointing to multiple frontend builds on one server not working

Tags: reactjs, nginx, ubuntu-18.04

Here is my situation: I have one Gateway server running nginx, and one front end server running nginx with two react app builds placed in separate folders.
What I need to do is setup nginx to proxy connections to specific build based on the url.

**Currently , all proxy connection from gateway server is going to first server block only instead to their respective block**

Below is the scenario :

biz.restro.app ==> biz-001.restro.app 
restro.app ==> fe-001.restro.app

Gateway server nginx config:

```
server {

        server_name restro.app;

        location / {

                proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_pass          https://fe-001.restro.app;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;

                # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/restro.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/restro.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = restro.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot



        server_name restro.app;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {

        server_name biz.restro.app;
        location / {

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

                # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
                proxy_pass          https://biz-001.restro.app;
                proxy_read_timeout  90;

                # Required for new HTTP-based CLI
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_request_buffering off;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }



    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/biz.restro.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/biz.restro.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = biz.restro.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

        server_name biz.restro.app;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Front end server nginx config:

```
server {

        server_name fe-001.restro.app;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html/user-build;
            index  index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/fe-001.restro.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/fe-001.restro.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = fe-001.restro.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;

        server_name fe-001.restro.app;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

server {

        server_name biz-001.restro.app;

        location / {
            root /var/www/html/admin-build;
            index  index.html;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/biz-001.restro.app/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/biz-001.restro.app/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
server {
    if ($host = biz-001.restro.app) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;

        server_name biz-001.restro.app:8000;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your gateway nginx is proxying to IP address and since both `fe-001.restro.app` and `biz-001.restro.app` are hosted on the same IP, it will take you to the default app(i.e `fe-001.restro.app`) in all cases.

Changing the following should work:
`proxy_set_header Host $host;` to `proxy_set_header Host 'biz-001.restro.app';`